# C# VSTO Outlook Outgoing Message Hyperlink

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am creating a C# VSTO add-in for Outlook 2010. I am attempting to generate a hyperlink at the insertion point of the active outgoing message that is being worked on (the hyperlink is inserted via a button on the message window ribbon). All other functions of the add-in (ribbon button, accessing the `ActiveInspector().CurrentItem`, etc.) work fine. I am working with this code:

```
object linktext = txtDisplayText.Text;
object result = "MY URL";
object missObj = Type.Missing;

Outlook.MailItem currentMessage = 
     Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
Word.Document doc = currentMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor;
object oRange = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
doc.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add
    (oRange, ref result, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref linktext, ref missObj);
```

When I run this code I get the message "Command failed." I suspect I am missing something either in regards to how Outlook uses Microsoft Word's editor for Outlook messages or in the way I have specified the selection object in `oRange`. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was indeed caused by the way the selection was defined for the `Hyperlinks.Add` command. Instead of an object type, the selection needed to be typed as a Microsoft Word Selection (due to the fact that Outlook uses Word as its editor):

```
Word.Selection objSel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
```

So to insert a hyperlink at the insertion point of an Outlook message during composition, the code has using statements for both Word and Outlook:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

And then this code:

```
object linktext = txtDisplayText.Text;
object result = "MY URL";
object missObj = Type.Missing;

Outlook.MailItem currentMessage = 
     Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
Word.Document doc = currentMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Word.Selection objSel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
doc.Hyperlinks.Add
     (objSel.Range, ref result, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref linktext, ref missObj);
```

Two other adjustments are worth noting. Because a `Word.Selection` type was used for the anchor of the hyperlink, the `Hyperlinks.Add` command needed to be changed from `doc.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add` to `doc.Hyperlinks.Add`. And because Outlook uses Microsoft's Word editor, the anchor for `doc.Hyperlinks.Add` used a range: `objSel.Range`.

Comment: Hey joe, thank you for posting your answer.  It helped me a lot actually.  But one minor thing.  If you were to add a new line to the hyperlink, how would you do it?  I am calling your code in a loop to add multiple hyperlinks but adding System.Environment.NewLine to my linktext results in a wired icon showing on the new line before my next link.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @dbnex14 I think you want to add the new line to the range object that contains the link. Try `objSel.Range.Text = @"\r\n";` Here's additional info: [How to Programmatically Insert Text into Word Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but that is just adding string "\r\n".  I also tried setting just to "\n" or objSel.Range.Text = System.Environment.NewLine but that wouldn't add new line either.  Much appreciated Joe!

Comment: @dbnex14 Am I misunderstanding? Don't you want to output a hyperlink followed by a newline followed by another link, etc? I see you've posted this question here: [Outlook VSTO - Add new line to WordEditor Document Hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983496/outlook-vsto-add-new-line-to-wordeditor-document-hyperlink). If I have time I'll play with the code this evening and continue this conversation where you posted this question (linked above).

Comment: You are correct, that is exactly what I want but doing objSel.Range.Text=@"\r\n" as you suggested just inserts "\r\n" string without new line.  If I have 10 links, I want them to show in 10 lines one under the other.  As you can see in my post you refered to above, I use System.Environment.NewLine concatenated to the link.  That works but shows the wired character at the beginning of each line. I am referencing Microsoft.Interop 14 (which is I believe Office 2010) library in my project.

Comment: @dbnex14 I posted my answer where your SO question appears. Apologies for typing `@"\r\n"` in my comment above. Was a typo and should not have the "@" symbol (which makes the backslash a literal string character instead of starting the escape sequence). In any case, ignore the comment completely as I now understand what's going on and have detailed what I believe to be the correct answer with your SO question. Cheers.

Comment: I'll take a look but I do remember trying several things including just "\n".  I'll take a look at your answer and let you know.  Much appreciated Joe!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class for modifying the message body (inserting a hyperlink) in the ItemSend event handler instead. You need to find the place where to paste a hyperlink `<a href=.../>`, modify the HTML well formed string and assign it back.

Comment: Eugene, the `ItemSend` event handler intercepts the message after the user sends it. I am using a custom ribbon button that I placed in the message ribbon for the user to insert the hyperlink and then continue working on the message. The `HTMLBody` property replaces the entire Outlook message, but I wish to insert text at the message text's insertion point (where one would see text appear when typing). I currently believe that I need to alter the range in some way to stop the `Hyperlinks.Add` from failing.

Comment: You need to insert a hyperlink in the existing HTML markup and then set it back. The `HTMLBody` property doesn't replace the entire Outlook message. What code did you try?

Comment: Eugene, `HTMLBody` wasn't the answer. See my code above. Thanks.

Comment: `HTMLBody` is an alternative way for getting the job done.

Comment: Eugene, if you'd like to post your code for making `HTMLBody` work with adding a hyperlink at the insertion point in an outgoing Outlook message (and returning the insertion point to the user's previous editable point after the hyperlink is created) I think myself and others would benefit from it.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes, using HTMLBody works but it is an alternative.  In some cases, we might not want to use HTMLBody but WordEditor.