# Outlook VSTO - Add new line to WordEditor Document Hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, outlook, vsto, newline

I am using following code to add hyperlinks to my MailItem

```
object link = url + System.Environment.NewLine;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem currentMessage = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = currentMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection sel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref result, ref missing, ref missing, ref link, ref missing);
```

While this does insert each link on new line in Outlook MailItem, it also shows a wired character in front of each new line starting the 2nd line:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried adding it to selection range like

```
sel.Range.Text = System.Environment.Newline;
```

, but that was not adding new line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Outlook uses the Microsoft Word editor to compose messages, Word's object model applies here. `sel` in your code represents the Selection object, which is the location of the insertion point in the message. Redefining the selection point after each hyperlink insertion let's Word know where to put the link.

```
doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref result, ref missing, ref missing, ref link, ref missing);
sel.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdLine); 
sel.InsertAfter("\n");
sel.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdLine);
```

`Environment.NewLine` is supposed to get the newline string as defined for the particular environment being used, but clearly does not work here hence `"\n"`. And I can't think of a way to make concatenating `"\n"` with the URL work as `link` is not a `string` and `Hyperlinks.Add` requires it to be an `object`.

Comment: Much appreciated @joeschwa.  Works like charm!